# Pandas: Flipping df-wide-values and index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I'm trying to flip values and index in this manner:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"day1":{"JOHN":"A","JANE":"B","JILL":"C"},"day2":{"JOHN":"A","JANE":"C","JILL":np.nan},"day3":{"JOHN":"C","JANE":"A","JILL":"B"}})
df
```

```
     day1   day2    day3
JOHN    A      A       C
JANE    B      C       A
JILL    C    NaN       B
```

looking for:

```
     day1    day2    day3
A    JOHN    JOHN    JANE
B    JANE    NaN     JILL
C    JILL    JANE    JOHN
```

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to tackle that. My mind jumps to pivoting somehow, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with convert first level of MultiIndex to column and column `0` append to `Index`, so possible use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with transpose:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0).set_index(0, append=True)['level_0'].unstack().T
print (df)
   day1  day2  day3
0                  
A  JOHN  JOHN  JANE
B  JANE   NaN  JILL
C  JILL  JANE  JOHN
```

Or use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with convert index to column and then remove missing values with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index').dropna().pivot('value','variable','index')
print (df)
variable  day1  day2  day3
value                     
A         JOHN  JOHN  JANE
B         JANE   NaN  JILL
C         JILL  JANE  JOHN
```